# coefplot: Putting names of regressions with vertical option

Tags: stata

Currently, I have the following code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
estimates clear 

gen year=.
replace year=1988 if foreign==0
replace year=1989 if foreign==1 

regress price mpg trunk length turn if year==1988
estimates store Year1988

regress price mpg trunk length turn if year==1989
estimates store Year1989

coefplot Year1988 Year1989, vertical keep(trunk) xline(0) xlabel("")
```

This generates:

[image]

However, I want to put custom names for each stored regression set of results like:

[image]

How can I do this? I tried `xtick` and `xlabel` but it doesn't work.

Note: Answer without `vertical` option can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383940/coefplot-putting-names-of-regressions-on-y-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the same:

```
sysuse auto, clear
estimates clear 

gen year=.
replace year=1988 if foreign==0
replace year=1989 if foreign==1 

regress price mpg trunk length turn if year==1988
estimates store Year1988

regress price mpg trunk length turn if year==1989
estimates store Year1989

local gap1 : display _dup(45) " "
local gap2 : display _dup(40) " "

coefplot Year1988 Year1989, vertical keep(trunk) xline(0) ///
coeflabels(trunk = `""|`gap1'|""1988`gap2'1989""') ///
xlabel(, notick labgap(0)) xline(0) legend(off)
```

[image]