# How to label y axis in coefplot?

Tags: stata, coefplot

How do I label/rename the variables on y axis?

```
sysuse auto, clear
regress price mpg trunk length turn if foreign==0
estimates store Option1
regress price mpg trunk length turn if foreign==1
estimates store Option2
coefplot Option1 Option2, drop(_cons) xline(1)
```

None of the option in this [coefplot: Putting names of regressions on y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383940/coefplot-putting-names-of-regressions-on-y-axis) is what I want. I want to to change  Mileage (mpg) to Mileage and so on.

Edit:
Sorry for not being clear in my question. I want to label variables on y axis like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

keep if rep78>=3 

regress mpg headroom i.rep##i.foreign 

coefplot, xline(0) omitted baselevels drop(_cons) /// 
headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}" /// 
0.foreign = "{bf:Car Type}" /// 
3.rep78#0.foreign = "{bf:Interaction Effects}") headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}" ///
```

I got this error message:

```
command headings is unrecognized r(199); –
```

Comment: My guess is that you're using `///` interactively. Evidently Stata thinks that `headings` is a command in your view and it can't find any such.  `///` is only allowed in do-files and programs. Interactively omit the `///` and type the command as one.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` works fine for me. Maybe you referred to variable labels instead of the variable names in `rename` before?

```
coefplot Option1 Option2, drop(_cons) xline(1) rename(mpg = Mileage)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. I want to label variabels on y axis like this: sysuse auto, clear
keep if rep78>=3
regress mpg headroom i.rep##i.foreign
coefplot, xline(0) omitted baselevels drop(_cons)               ///
    headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}"                     ///
             0.foreign = "{bf:Car Type}"                      ///
             3.rep78#0.foreign = "{bf:Interaction Effects}")                                                         
headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}"                     ///
command headings is unrecognized
r(199);

Comment: Please update your question with the new code, this is hard to read